# How to calculate the average of a Project Reactor Flux?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a method that returns a `Flux<SensorData>`, let's suppose SensorData has a field `measure: Integer`.

I would like to calculate the average value of measure of the whole Flux. How can it be done?

```
val sensorFlux: Flux<SensorData> = sensorRepository.findAll()
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Mono<Double> average = sensorFlux.collect(Collectors.averagingInt(SensorData::getMeasure))
```

Comment: please note that collect reacts on the `onComplete` event, which could never come if the `Flux` is "infinite" (sensor data potentially being such an infinite Flux)

Comment: @SimonBaslé thanks. But how could we possibly compute an average without waiting for the completion? The alternative would be, I guess, to have a running average, and thus to return a Flux<Double>, which would emit a new average every time the sensor emits.

Comment: yeah in that case you would need to window the source and compute a running average over a time period, probably

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it with an auxiliary object:

```
val average = sensorFlux.map { it.measure }
                .map { Measure(1, it) }
                .reduce { t: Measure, u: Measure -> Measure(t.elements + u.elements, t.sum + u.sum) }
                .map { it.sum / it.elements }

---

data class Measure(var elements: Int, var sum: Long)
```